# Passing variables/values from python script to shell script

Tags: python, bash, parameter-passing

This is my use case: I have a python script that returns the name of a remote server and a file path from a config file. I need a way to use those two or more parameterized variables and their values as input for my shell script which will then sync files by connecting to the remote server. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Use a pipe (`|`)

Comment: @wpercy -Pipe(|) that works in a shell command. Here the variable and corresponding values are in a python script ( dictionary object) and I need the output to be an input to my bash script. Should I just call the bash script in my python script?

Comment: The Python script cannot "return" anything; it can only write to standard output. A pipe is appropriate if your `bash` script can parse what it reads from its standard input into the appropriate values. Right now, your question is too vague to provide an appropriate answer.

Comment: no, you should call your python script from the command line, output the values in your dict to stdout and pipe them into the bash script

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you were looking for.  I have a python script that prints out 3 lines, each a different value.  For you, a[0] would be the server, a[1] the first file, and a[2] the second.  The number of lines is arbitrary and this would work for any number, one per line, and allow spaces in the file names.

The "<(" executes what is inside and creates something like a pipe, which the readarray command reads (it takes standard input, namely "<")

```
> readarray a < <(python -c 'print "myserver:8080"; print "file1 which may have spaces"; print "another file"')
> echo ${a[0]}
myserver:8080
> echo ${a[1]}
file1 which may have spaces
> echo ${a[2]}
another file
```

Comment: that is clever! thanks a lot, let me try to see if that will work else will poke around some more with detailed questions and code snippets.